# How to use Bouncy Castle lightweight API with AES and PBE

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle, jce

I have a block of ciphertext that was created using the JCE algorithim "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC". The provider is BouncyCastle. What I'd like to do it decrypt this ciphertext using the BouncyCastle lightweight API. I don't want to use JCE because that requires installing the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

Documentation seems to be thin on the ground when it comes to using BC with PBE and AES.

Here's what I have so far. The decryption code runs without exception but returns rubbish.

The encryption code,

```
String password = "qwerty";
String plainText = "hello world";

byte[] salt = generateSalt();
byte[] cipherText = encrypt(plainText, password.toCharArray(), salt);

private static byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte salt[] = new byte[8];
    SecureRandom saltGen = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    saltGen.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, char[] password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);

    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
    SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

    Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
    encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

    return encryptionCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

The decryption code,

```
byte[] decryptedText = decrypt(cipherText, password.getBytes(), salt);

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] password, byte[] salt) throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    BlockCipher engine = new AESEngine();
    CBCBlockCipher cipher = new CBCBlockCipher(engine);

    PKCS5S1ParametersGenerator keyGenerator = new PKCS5S1ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    keyGenerator.init(password, salt, 20);

    CipherParameters keyParams = keyGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256);
    cipher.init(false, keyParams);

    byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[cipherText.length];
    int numBytesCopied = cipher.processBlock(cipherText, 0, decryptedBytes, 0);

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried this and it seemed to work. Borrowed heavily from the BC class `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.test.PBETest`

```
private byte[] decryptWithLWCrypto(byte[] cipher, String password, byte[] salt, final  int iterationCount)
        throws Exception
{
    PKCS12ParametersGenerator pGen = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
    final byte[] pkcs12PasswordBytes = PBEParametersGenerator
            .PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passwordChars);
    pGen.init(pkcs12PasswordBytes, salt, iterationCount);
    CBCBlockCipher aesCBC = new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine());
    ParametersWithIV aesCBCParams = (ParametersWithIV) pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128);
    aesCBC.init(false, aesCBCParams);
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(aesCBC,
            new PKCS7Padding());
    byte[] plainTemp = new byte[aesCipher.getOutputSize(cipher.length)];
    int offset = aesCipher.processBytes(cipher, 0, cipher.length, plainTemp, 0);
    int last = aesCipher.doFinal(plainTemp, offset);
    final byte[] plain = new byte[offset + last];
    System.arraycopy(plainTemp, 0, plain, 0, plain.length);
    return plain;
}
```

Comment: the line  pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128);  is that setting the key length ?

Comment: @george_h: 256 is the key length; 128 is the IV length.

Answer (score 9):

There were a few problems with your decrypt method:

```
private static byte[] decrypt(final byte[] bytes, final char[] password, final byte[] salt) throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    final PBEParametersGenerator keyGenerator = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    keyGenerator.init(PKCS12ParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(password), salt, 20);
    final CipherParameters keyParams = keyGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128);

    final BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()), new PKCS7Padding());
    cipher.init(false, keyParams);

    final byte[] processed = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(bytes.length)];
    int outputLength = cipher.processBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length, processed, 0);
    outputLength += cipher.doFinal(processed, outputLength);

    final byte[] results = new byte[outputLength];
    System.arraycopy(processed, 0, results, 0, outputLength);
    return results;
}
```

The main problems were the way you were carrying out the decryption without using a block cipher and the missing IV size to the `generateDerivedParameters` method. I saw the first problem pretty quickly, the 2nd one was much less obvious. I only discovered that one through looking at a Bouncy Castle test called [PBETest](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/java/crypto/src/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/Attic/PBETest.java).

Comment: Thanks laz. Your solution works perfectly but since Greg answered first it's only fair I accept his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I somehow missed that GregS provided an answer when he did. I'm interested in finding out why the size for that initialization vector needs to be 128 and how someone is supposed to know that is required. That was the part that got me hung up.

Comment: Great minds think alike :) I knew that AES is a 128-bit block cipher, so the IV for AES will always be 128 bits. I could have used BlockCipher.getBlockSize() * 8 to be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial to generate the key exactly as the JCE counterparts. I just briefly browsed your code. Found at least one discrepancy. JCE uses PKCS12 generator but you use PKCS5S1.

I am not surprised if there are other differences. You need to compare your code against BC source.

Comment: Thanks for that ZZ. I tried using PKCS12 as well but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your encryption method accepts a password as a char array but the decrypt accepts password as bytes.  In Java chars are 16-bit while bytes are 8-bit.  This could result in different keys for encrypt/decrypt and perhaps explain the issues with gibberish decrypted results?