# User Authentication by Decryption

Tags: authentication, hash, encryption

I'm trying to avoid DB access upon authentication to improve performance

a valid solution after lots of searching seems to be storing an encrypted string in cookie and try to decrypt it upon authentication.

Thus, I am wondering if the following is a good idea:

1. transmit everything via SSL (I'm lazy..)
2. set a global constant secret key in my program
3. generate a new random verification string upon registration and password change, store it in the User object
4. generate an encrypted verification string with verification string and secret key
5. store the unencrypted and encrypted verification strings in the cookie
6. when user tries to login, decrypt the verification string and check against the original verification string

if it is an "OK" idea, how do I actually make it work, like:

what encryption method should I use, AES-256?

how do I do this kind of encryption/decryption in Java, using Bouncycastle?

if it is not a good idea, what should I do to avoid querying DB on authentication?

thans in advance!

Comment: You can promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe above is called “RememberMe”.
Two approaches to solve your problem:

1)  Create your own authentication framework.

Upon the successful authentication put in a cookie an encrypted value of a username (I strongly not recommend to use hashing; also please do not put the user password value).

The cookie should be persistent at most for 2 weeks.

For encryption please use AES-256 encryption with BouncyCastle:
[How to use Bouncy Castle lightweight API with AES and PBE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957513/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-lightweight-api-with-aes-and-pbe)
Please do not put any plain values in cookies.
If your framework success to decrypt the cookie – the user is authenticated.  If your framework cannot decrypt the cookie or the cookie does not exist - the user is not authenticated.
Upon the logout please clean the cookie.

2)  Please consider to use the Spring Security framework: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html

It is the great framework and solves a lot of authentication / authorization problems.

Your problem is solved by the “RememberMe” feature:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-remember-me

Please tell me if you need any additional clarifications.

Best regards,

Michael