# AES 256 Decrypt with IV and Salt using Bouncycastle

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin, cryptography, bouncycastle

Currently I am working on an project where we are building an server side and client side application (mobile device, using Xamarin). We are encrypting and decrypting the data (using AES...), with the exact following implementation for the server-side: 
[Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Unforunately we cannot use that implementation within our Xamarin project. So we would like to use Bouncycastle to decrypt the data. I came across the following Java implementation of Bouncycastle, and tried to modify it in order to get it to work with .NET. [How to use Bouncy Castle lightweight API with AES and PBE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957513/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-lightweight-api-with-aes-and-pbe)

Resulting in:

```
private byte[] decryptWithLWCrypto(string cipherText, String password, int iterationCount)
        {
            // Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
            // [32 bytes of Salt] + [32 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
            var cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            // Get the saltbytes by extracting the first 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var salt = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the IV bytes by extracting the next 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 64 bytes from the cipherText string.
            var cipher = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

            Pkcs12ParametersGenerator pGen = new Pkcs12ParametersGenerator(new Sha256Digest());
            byte[] pkcs12PasswordBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(password);//PbeParametersGenerator
            pGen.Init(pkcs12PasswordBytes, salt, iterationCount);
            CbcBlockCipher aesCBC = new CbcBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256));//was AesEngine

            ParametersWithIV aesCBCParams = new ParametersWithIV(pGen.GenerateDerivedParameters(256, 128), ivStringBytes);
            aesCBC.Init(false, aesCBCParams);
            PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(aesCBC,
                    new Pkcs7Padding());
            byte[] plainTemp = new byte[aesCipher.GetOutputSize(cipher.Length)];
            int offset = aesCipher.ProcessBytes(cipher, 0, cipher.Length, plainTemp, 0);
            int last = aesCipher.DoFinal(plainTemp, offset);
            byte[] plain = new byte[offset + last];
            System.Array.Copy(plainTemp, 0, plain, 0, plain.Length);

            return plain;
        }
```

Now I get the following error, because I am trying to adapt the sample from Java to AES256:

```
Additional information: invalid parameter passed to Rijndael init - Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ParametersWithIV
```

At this point I tried a lot, the error itself explains what is going on. But I lack the experience with Bouncycastle to get it to work using AES256, IV and salt. I read that you can't use `AesEngine`, so you have to switch to `RijndaelEngine` for AES256.

Does anyone have an working implementation using this setup? Within the Xamarin app `System.Security.Cryptography` cannot be used.

Comment: I did used the same setup for my xamarin apps, I've posted the class which has all the stufh in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/NAB1ftW9 look at the class CifradoSimetrico. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I can't use `System.Security.Cryptography` the dev from the Xamarin app uses an PCL construction (I am helping him out by implementing an native Windows test application, so he can easily take over the same code).

Comment: I'm using that class in a Xamarin Forms project (PCL). The PCL project is only the Forms project, there are two native projects which can use the full framework. Just add it to the .Droid and .iOS app and create and register an interface as a Dependency, then retrieve the interface to use the inherited class, this can help you if it's the first time using Xamarin Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/.

Comment: `new RijndaelEngine()` will give you AES and if you provide a 32 byte key, then it will be AES-256. Just reduce the IV size to 16 bytes.

Comment: The error here is that both the salt and IV size are directly computed from the key size, while they are actually not related. AES is Rijndael with the block size restricted to 128 bits and the key sizes restricted to 128, 192 or 256 bits.